# Unable to understand the error in Guile Scheme Code

Tags: scheme, pascals-triangle, mit-scheme, guile

I am trying to print a Pascal's Triangle on terminal using Guile Scheme.
[What is Pascal's Triangle?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle)

Here is the script:

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/guile \
-e main -s 
!#
(define (fact-iter product counter max-count)
    (if (> counter max-count)
         product
         (fact-iter (* counter product) (+ counter 1) max-count)))

(define (factorial n)
    (fact-iter 1 1 n))

(define (n-C-r n r) 
    (/ (factorial n) (* (factorial (- n r)) (factorial r))
    )
)


(define (row-iter r l n)
    (cond   ((= r 0) ((display 1) (row-iter (+ r 1) l n)))
            ((and (> r 0) (< r l)) ((display (n-C-r l r)) (display " ") (row-iter (+ r 1) l n)))
            ((= r l) (display 1))
    )
)


(define (line-iter l n)
    (cond ((<= l n) ( (row-iter 0 l n)
                        (line-iter (+ l 1) n) ) )
    )
)

(define (pascal-triangle n)
    (line-iter 0 n) )

(define (main args)
    (pascal-triangle (string->number (car (cdr args)) 10))
    )
```

File name is pascalTriangle.scm
The *Shebang notation* on the top has correct path to guile.
I have given the permissions by *chmod +x pascalTriangle.scm*
Run the program using the command *./pascalTriangle.scm 5*

When run, the above script, the following output/error is observed:

> 1Backtrace: In ice-9/boot-9.scm:
>      157: 5 [catch #t #<catch-closure ac8400> ...]
>   In unknown file:
>         ?: 4 [apply-smob/1 #<catch-closure ac8400>]
>   In ice-9/boot-9.scm:
>         63: 3 [call-with-prompt prompt0 ...]
>   In ice-9/eval.scm:
>       432: 2 [eval # #]
>   In /home/tarunmaganti/./pascalTriangle.scm:
>         27: 1 [line-iter 0 4]
>   In unknown file:
>          ?: 0 [#<unspecified> #<unspecified>]
>
> ERROR: In procedure #<unspecified>:
>   ERROR: Wrong type to apply: #<unspecified>

Notice that, the first character of the output is 1 which implies that the code executed until first part of procedure *row-iter* i.e., (display 1) and there might be an error after it.

But the output says that error is in procedure *line-iter*. I do not understand.
I would appreciate if any error in the program is pointed-out and corrected to make it print a Pascal's Triangle.

Edit1: I edited the error/output text, I replaced '<' and '>' with HTML entities. The text inside the angular brackets wasn't visible before.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have added excess parentheses around your consequence expressions in `cond`. Since `cond` has explicit `begin` you code that looks like this today:

```scm
(define (row-iter r l n)
  (cond ((= r 0)
         ;; you see the double (( ?
         ((display 1)
          (row-iter (+ r 1) l n)))

        ((and (> r 0) (< r l))
         ;; you see the double (( ?
         ((display (n-C-r l r))
          (display " ")
          (row-iter (+ r 1) l n)))

        ((= r l)
         ;; without double (( and thus ok
         (display 1))))
```

Needs to have it's excess parentheses removed like this:

```scm
(define (row-iter r l n)
  (cond ((= r 0)
         (display 1)
         (row-iter (+ r 1) l n))

        ((and (> r 0) (< r l))
         (display (n-C-r l r))
         (display " ")
         (row-iter (+ r 1) l n))

        ((= r l)
         (display 1))))
```

If you would have used `if` instead you would have to use `begin`:

```scm
(define (row-iter r l n)
  (if (= r 0)
      (begin
        (display 1)
        (row-iter (+ r 1) l n))
      (if (and (> r 0) (< r l))
          (begin
            (display (n-C-r l r))
            (display " ")
            (row-iter (+ r 1) l n))          
          (display 1))))
```

Just fixing this procedure wont fix you problem since you have the same error in `line-iter` as well. You might see double `((` in the beginning of each `cond` term but unless you are doing something fancy you should not expect it anywhere else.

When adding excess parentheses `((display "something") #t)` it gets interpreted as `(display "something")` will return a procedure and that you want to check what the result of that procedure with argument `#t` will become. When all the parts is evaluated it fails since then it finds out the undefined value is not a procedure. There are cases where it works:

```scm
((if (< x 0) - +) x 1) ; absolute increment value without changing sign
```

Here you see the first part gets evaluated to the result of evaluating `-` when `x` is less than zero. If it's `-10` the result would be `-11` and if it is `10` the procedure applied will be the evaluation of `+` with the result `11`.

Later it will find that the value `3` isn't a procedure and you get th eerror. and to get the result Scheme should do (apply 3 '(#t))`and it detects that 3 (in your case what`desiplay`returns which is an unspecified value) 
Scheme interprets this by evaluating`(display (n-C-r l r)` which prints something and the returned value, which by the spec i undefined and thus free choice of the implementers, is then applied as a procedure because of excess parentheses.

In Guile the result of values undefined in the spec becomes a singleton that displays `#<unspecified>` and that is ignored by the REPL. You might find a Scheme implementation where the unspecified value is a procedure that takes no arguments where your implementation will work flawlessly but will not be portable.

Comment: How do I resolve it, then? What should I change it to?

Comment: @TarunMaganti You change it from `((display (n-C-r l r))` to `(display (n-C-r l r)`. Unless it's part of a special form, like in `let` bindings, every pranethesis represents calling a procedure. You have the same in algol languages if you add `()` at the end of statements like `somefun()()`.

Comment: I changed the line as follows - "((and (> r 0) (< r l)) (display (n-C-r l r) (display " ") (row-iter (+ r 1) l n))" But isn't the syntax like this, "cond (<predicate> <expression>)" and I had to run multiple procedures in the expression, so used the brackets to group them.  If I removed the brackets syntax became something like this..."cond (<predicate> <expression> <expression> <expression>)", is that valid?

Comment: I ran it after the changes and the error was exactly the same!?

Comment: I tried introducing a function defined as -

(define (disp l r) (display (n-C-r l r)))
and used it. 

I don't know if Scheme substitutes the function and interprets it or goes to a memory location like in C/C++,but the error occurred even after the change.

Comment: @TarunMaganti `cond` and explicit `begin` so a `cond` term looks like `(predicate consequent1 consequent2 ...)` if it didn't it would look like `(predicate (begin consequent1 consequent2 ...))`.  You have several places where you have extra parentheses around the consequences and not only that location so you need to remove the excess from all the places.

Answer (score 0):

The error as stated by Sylwester in his answer is in `((display (n-C-r l r)) (display " ") (row-iter (+ r 1) l n)))` expression. The statement indeed interprets this by evaluating `((display (n-C-r l r))` which prints something and return undefined value and is applied as a procedure considering `((display (n-C-r l r))` as excessively parenthesized.

I resolved the problem using the Sequencing. The **begin** special form is used to combine multiple statements and returns the value of the last statement.
[Sequencing in MIT-Scheme](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Sequencing.html). This worked in guile scheme too.

Syntax of **begin** special form: `(begin <e1> <e2> <e3>....<en>)`
 It returns return value of `<en>` expression.

Here is the changed code:

```
(define (row-iter n r) 
    (cond ((= r 0) (begin (display 1) (display " ") (row-iter n (+ r 1))))
          ((and (> r 0) (< r n)) (begin (display (n-C-r n r)) (display " ") (row-iter n (+ r 1))))
          ((= r n) (display 1))
    )
)
```

Although the output isn't properly formatted as a "triangle", we can get left indented pascal triangle after changing the code.

By running *`./pascalTriangle 5`*, we get the output as

```
1    
1 1    
1 2 1    
1 3 3 1    
1 4 6 4 1    
1 5 10 10 5 1
```

Comment: Since `cond` has explicit `begin` so more than one consequent can just be put as elements besides the predicate. The first term would be like `((= r 0) (display 1) (display " ") (row-iter n (+ r 1)))`

Comment: Do you mean implicit? I tried that but it didn't seem to work. :/